# How can I send additional parameters via ng2-file-upload when I upload a file

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-file-upload

I have created two selects and want to send their values as parameters to the backend during upload. Do you know how to do that? Can you help me please?

My Code:

```
// Select Forms
 // Month form
    this.sendMonthsForm = this.fb.group({
      monthsValue: [null]
    });
    // Year form
    this.sendYearsForm = this.fb.group({
      yearsValue: [null]
    });
```

```
// Upload
  this.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: `${environment.baseUrl}/upload?title=SuSa&context=${year}&period=${month}`,
        maxFileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
        allowedFileType: ['csv', 'xls', 'xlsx'],
        authToken: `Bearer ${currentUser.auth_token}`,
      });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Custom Headers in ng2-file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568061/how-to-add-custom-headers-in-ng2-file-upload)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568061/how-to-add-custom-headers-in-ng2-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

```
uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
  url: URL,
  headers: [{ name: 'Authorization', value: 'Bearer ejy...' }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: `${environment.baseUrl}/upload?title=SuSa&context=${year}&period=${month}`,
        maxFileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
        additionalParameter:{uploaderparams1:'its-value',uploaderparams2:'its-value'},
        allowedFileType: ['csv', 'xls', 'xlsx'],
        authToken: `Bearer ${currentUser.auth_token}`,
      });
```